# c++ simple sum in for loop

Tags: c++, gcc, loops, for-loop

i am using g++ (GCC) 4.6.0 and i am having trouble to producing the correct result. given the following simple for loop in c++

```
  void sum(){
  int sum;
  for(int i=0,sum=0;i<=10;sum+=i,++i);
  cout << sum << endl;
  }
```

the output is giving me 0. suppose within the for loop i added

```
  cout << sum << endl;
```

it give me 0,1,3... until the very last line 0;

I think the reason I am getting 0 is because variable shadowing in the for loop? so I tried ::sum 
as in ::sum=0, and ::sum +=i. but it complains by the compiler. Also I tried

```
  for(sum=0,int i=0;i<=10;sum+=i,++i);
```

the compiler also complains about not having primary expression in the first clause in the for loop

Comment: Please include the results you actually expect this to produce.

Comment: @Martin: Why answer in a comment? Answer in an answer... except that several people already did.

Comment: A while loop would be even sweeter here: http://ideone.com/gdm6O :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int i=0,sum=0` is *not* the same as `int i=0; sum=0;`. It is one statement that declares *two* variables.

This means that you are *shadowing* the outer `sum`:

```
void sum() {
  int sum; // <-- one `sum`
  for (int i=0,sum=0;i<=10;sum+=i,++i) {} // <-- second `sum`
  cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Only a declaration statement like that can be in the first clause of the `for` preamble (think about whether `sum=0,int i=0` would be valid elsewhere in your code), but you can workaround this issue by [pulling out the "initialisation" to `0` entirely](http://codepad.org/kuyLsV1z):

```
void sum() {
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; sum += i, ++i) {}
   cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Or, [so that it's actually legible](http://codepad.org/VgaGI1kK):

```
void sum() {
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      sum += i;
   }
   cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: @dalle: If you click on the links, you'll see that I did not.

Comment: @dalle: On the comma operator, `[2003: 5.18/1]` says: "[..] All side effects (1.9) of the left expression [..] are performed **before** the evaluation of the right expression." (emphasis mine)

Comment: But now you have edited the answer. you had `sum += ++i` at first, which is not the same as `sum += i, ++i`.

Comment: @dalle: OK. That must have been one of the very first revisions, whilst I was looking up that clause; it wasn't there for long!

Comment: Yes, true, probably one of the first revisions. Anyway, +1 now when you have changed it.

Comment: I use to work with C and works just nicely.. the syntax grammar in c++ for(for-init-statement condition opt; expression_opt) statement). where for-init-statement:expression-statement or simple-declaration.. i don't see anything wrong with the syntax except for the hint in primary-expression.

Comment: @cplusnewbieeeee: I don't understand the problem. Which syntax are you talking about? You've shown us several, and we've shown you several back.

Comment: suppose it was variable overshadowing why can't I use for(::sum=0,int i=0;i<=10;::sum+=i,++i){} since I have int sum outside of the for scope.

Comment: @cplusnewbieeeee: Since when is `sum=0, int i = 0` considered a valid expression anywhere in C++? The comma isn't starting a new statement (the semicolons do that); you only get _one_!

Answer (score 8):

Really, you *have* to use the identifier `sum` three times for three different things? :-S

Just write it readbly:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) { sum += i; }
```

No more confusion, no more shadowing, no more uninitialized variables. Who are you trying to trick? Think about your replacement who will have to learn and understand your code!

Tip: Turn on compiler warnings!

PS: Before anyone talks about efficiency and starts counting CPU cycles: a) don't. b) hug your wife. c) compare the assembly of this code and your code.

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to:

```
 void sum(){
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<=10;sum+=i,++i); // all work is in for loop
  cout << sum << endl;
 }
```

Some (older) compilers wouldn't allow your original code, because you were defining a second `sum` inside your for loop which was hiding the original one. So, it was accumulating correctly *within* the for loop, but the `sum` defined outside the for loop was left untouched. For a little more detail:

```
int i = 0, sum = 0;
```

is the same as:

```
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;
```

Comment: I know I can do sum=0 outside of the for loop. but I want to take advantage of the inital phase of the for loop.

Comment: @cplusnewbieeeee: Why? It is no more efficient to do so, limits the visibility of sum to inside of the for loop, and makes the code less readable (as Kerrek SB rightly points out). Fewer lines of code != better code.

Comment: Note that the gcc behaviour is actually compliant with the standard.

Comment: @pmr: yeah, I'm thinking of older compilers I've used that technically weren't compliant. In this case, that bug would be a "feature".

Comment: @Ben I never doubted that you know it. IMHO The wording you used in the answer just makes it sound like it's the other way around.

Comment: There was nothing invalid about the code before. It just wasn't what the OP meant to write. Pre-ISO `for` loop scoping may have been different in that regard, but we don't care about that in 2011!

Comment: @Tomalak: You must not have to work with really old code. :) It's good to know these things if for no other reason so that when the whippersnappers ask you why something was done a certain way you can tell them.

Comment: @BenHocking: Absolutely, but the edit to your answer is most welcome. To imply that the original code is invalid standard C++ is flat-out wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You have two different `sum` variables. One declared in the

```
int sum;
```

line, and another one declared in the initializing declaration of your for loop.

The first part of a `for` statement is *either* a single declaration *or* an expression. In the latter case, the expression can consist of several assignments separated by comma operators, but you cannot mix and match  declarations and expressions in one `for` loop. Thus, `int i=0, sum=0` will be parsed as *one declaration* that declares `i` and `sum`. So in your loop you increase the *inner* `sum`, but after the loop only the *outer* one is visible, and that has still has whichever garbage value it started out with.

(Also, shame on you for putting the meat of the loop in the update expression instead of in the body!)

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Solution is to do this this way:

```
void sum(){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<=10;sum+=i,++i);
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why did you put the `;` after for-loop? Because of this you have 10 iterations of loop without any output and finally you have your result - zero.