# Save a For Loop Value after each iteration and sum those values for a total (without using a Function)

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

I really hate to ask this here as it feels like it should be super simple to figure out.  I have been racking my brain for half the day on this trying multiple ways and cannot seem to figure it out.  Posting here was a last resort...

I have a 1D array (non-vector).  Separating the evens and odds via a FOR loop and nested IF statement.  It properly returns the correct integers from the array via the IF statement respectively.  The problem is how to logically add each integers iteration to get a sum while in the FOR loop and/or IF statement.

As the title states, I would prefer to do this without a Function.

**Assume all necessary headers are incorporated and Main() & all brackets not related to the following code is correct.

---

```
int eo_array[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };

cout << sizeof(eo_array) / sizeof(eo_array[0]);  //verifying the size of the array is what it should be

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(eo_array) / sizeof(eo_array[0]); i++) {
        
    //first part of if statement is for even numbers
    if (eo_array[i] % 2 == 0) {
        
        cout << eo_array[i] << endl;
                    
    }
    //else part of if statement is for odd numbers
    else {

        cout << eo_array[i] << endl;

    }
}
```

---

Output (F5):
Size of array: 8

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

As you can see in the output.  The program is properly displaying all numbers (even and odd) in the code.  If you were to comment out one or the other cout statements in the IF or ELSE area you will also see the appropriate even/odd only.

Tried placing new variables to temporarily store the value or eo_array, however if there is a declaration prior to the IF statement that value will overwrite whatever is stored while in the IF statement on the next FOR loop go around.

TLDR: How do I save the eo_array value each time it iterates via the FOR loop?  The end goal is to add together all numbers of even or odd respectively and cout that final value.

Comment: Define the variable you want to use for saving, and initialise it, BEFORE the loop.   That way, it exists throughout the loop, changes made in the loop persist from one iteration to the next, and will still exist after the loop completes (until end of its enclosing scope).   A variable that is defined in the loop body is created (and initialised) at the start of every iteration and ceases to exist when each iteration is complete (so doesn't persist between iterations of the loop).

Comment: Side note: as of C++17, `sizeof(eo_array) / sizeof(eo_array[0])` is spelled `std::size(eo_array))`. Because it adds valuable compile-time defense against array decay, it's worth implementing it by hand if you need to work with older standard revisions. See [possible implementations 3 and 4](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size#Possible_implementation) for how.

Comment: Side note: Careful making assumptions about what people will-or-will-not assume. With programming, the devil is in the details. It doesn't matter here, but a lot of the time (maybe even most of the time) the mistake the asker's looking for help with is in that bit they deemed unimportant and left out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ simple sum in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989360/c-simple-sum-in-for-loop)

Comment: I can not find what is problem.
Maybe... some restrictions prohibit natural/ordinal coding way?
If so, you should clarify what kind of restrictions are really annoying you. 
(I can find the restriction "without function" only.)

Comment: `+=` is your friend. However, in case the array always contains integers from `1` to `n`, then the sum of odd integers is `(n + n % 2) * (n + n % 2) / 4` and the sum of even integers is `(n / 2) * (n / 2 + 1)`. No `for` or `if` are needed. (Maybe just two extra variables for the common subexpressions of `n + n % 2` and `n / 2`, but that‘s all, that's it.)

Comment: Thank you for the replies and the downvotes (which I kind of expected really :))

@Peter - This comment helped the most.  After putting a different variable out of the FOR scope I was able to procure the results I wanted.

Something interesting, if I put a "=" after the less than in (i < sizeof.....) the output is correct when the entire array is added together however I also get a memory address along with the correct sum of all numbers = 36

The link was good to see, I have not seen or knew you could establish multiple variables in a FOR, good to know.

Comment: Added prior to FOR loop:

int eo_sumeven = 0;
int eo_sumodd = 0;

And used inside the IF statement:
eo_sumeven += eo_array[i];

Used inside the ELSE statement: 
eo_sumodd += eo_array[i];

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdc++.h>
//custom library added from github = has lots of headers included

using namespace std;


int main(){

int eo_array[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };

cout << "Size of array: " << sizeof(eo_array) / sizeof(eo_array[0]) << endl << endl;

int eo_sumeven = 0;
int eo_sumodd = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(eo_array) / sizeof(eo_array[0]); i++) {
            
    //first part of if statement is for even numbers
    if (eo_array[i] % 2 == 0) {
        
        eo_sumeven += eo_array[i];

        //cout << eo_array[i] << endl;
                                
    }
    //else part of if statement is for odd numbers
    else {

        eo_sumodd += eo_array[i];
        //cout << eo_array[i] << endl;

    }
            
}

cout << "The sum of even numbers in the array is: " << eo_sumeven << endl << "The sum of odd numbers in the array is: " << eo_sumodd << endl;

}
```

Comment: If the `<stdc++.h>` is anything akin to GCC's `<bits/stdc++.h>` then please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) Further, it would be far better to include the required *standard* headers.

Comment: Yuppers. `<bits/stdc++.h>` or any similar God Header pulling more than you need loads the gun, and `using namespace std;` [takes the safety off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4581301). Use both of them and it becomes stupidly easy to shoot yourself in the foot. Don't do this to yourself and most definitely don't recommend it to other people. [Simple example](https://godbolt.org/z/vd7KT9bGa)

Comment: Had to roll through browsing history but I found the link to the STDC++.h

https://gist.github.com/velicast/6022859

As for the library, interesting read.  Also, after Vstudio update, that file also seemed to be nuked from it's directory (I didn't make a new folder "bits" I threw it in with all the other .h files.  It works, until VStudio updates.  I totally get the point.

I had found that multi-library from a prominent C++ website that cited it as a library that should be used, which turned into a github rabbit hole.  Just FYI

Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: If you have your build system set up exactly right to use precompiled headers, `<bits/stdc++.h>` can save time writing the code when in competition and debugging/maintaining is less important (in competition if you have to stop and debug, you've probably lost) On the other hand, if you don't have the build system set up correctly, you'll find that including the whole C++ Standard library increases your build times by about an order of magnitude for small programs, rapidly eating up the time saved by typing one header if you have to build more than once.

Comment: If this prominent site is targeting or contributed to by competitive programmers, you'll see a lot of advice that's just plain stupid in real-world coding. The goal of competition code is to write a program that provides the correct result when run once under ideal circumstances. The real world is far from ideal, and a good program needs to run for decades without error on a wide variety of target systems while users feed it typos and malicious inputs. The goals are nearly orthogonal.